# How to evaluate an expression in a pandas df that finds the greater of two variables?

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I want to do compute a value that is the maximum of two columns, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,3,5],
                    'b':[6,4,2] } )

df['c'] = df.eval('maximum(a,b)')
```

I am getting  'ValueError: "maximum" is not a supported function'. This is true even when I use `engine='python'`. Surprising because `maximum` is a `ufunc`. The exact computation required must be provided as an external string.
How should I proceed?

```
eval('maximum(df.a, df.b)')
```

does work fine, but I'd rather not do this for readability reasons.

Comment: What's wrong on `df["c"] = np.maximum(df.a, df.b)` ? Or `df["c"] = df[["a", "b"]].max(axis=1)`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - The computation must be provided as an external string! I hate using eval, but we have no choice in this as the formula is entered in a gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) as an external function:

```
from numpy import maximum

df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':[1,3,5],
                    'b':[6,4,2] } )

df['c'] = df.eval('@maximum(a,b)')
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  6  6
1  3  4  4
2  5  2  5
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks - could you possibly explain why "@" works? I could not find anything about it on the documentation of `pandas.eval()`. I had `from numpy import minimum`, but I was still getting the `ValueError` without the `@`. In fact, the docs suggest that it should automatically use any function that is in `locals()`, but clearly it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["C"] = df[["A", "B"]].max(axis=1)
```

The intuition behind this is that with axis = 1, it selects the max across the rows horizontally vice versa the opposite is true if you want to select between columns